# Connect to google cloud SQL with django from google VM

Tags: sql, django, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to connect to my google SQL database from my VM instance with django and I get the following error:

```
private key file "./Google Keys/client-key.pem" has group or world access; permis
sions should be u=rw (0600) or less
```

how can it be fixed?

(Note: it is working from my local machine but not from VM instance :/)

Comment: If file permissions are your problem, and you need the key permissions to be 0600 then you can use the `chmod` command. `chmod 600 client-key.pem`

Comment: @anowlinorbit thank you! how can I execute it? do I need to do it localy on cmd with gcp installed or on the server somehow?

Comment: If this error is being generated from your Django host, then you need to run this at the command line on the Django host. In the example I gave, you need to be in the same directory as your `client-key.pem`

Comment: @Tomergt45 where you able to connect to the Cloud SQL instance from the Compute Engine Virtual Machine after using the `chmod` command and giving the key the correct permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a security warning trying to help you keep your private key safe. On linux, you can modify the permissions of the file using the following command:

```sh
chmod 600 "Google Keys/client-key.pem"
```

This will limit who can read and write to the file, making it so unprivileged users won't be able to get at the contents. You can read more about `chmod` in the [chmod man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod).